# Unable to add an object to Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project in Angular with Firebase. I am unable to push an object to Firebase Database.

Here is an [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adding-an-object-to-firebase?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) representing my issue.

**component.ts**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
export class AppComponent {
  courses$: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.courses$ = this.db.list('/courses');
  }
  addCourse(course: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.courses$.push(course.value);
    course.value = '';
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter courses..." (keyup.enter)="addCourse(course)" #course>
</div>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let course of courses$ | async">{{course.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export class AppComponent {
  courses: AngularFireList<string[]>;
  courses$: Observable<any[]>
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.courses = this.db.list('/courses');
    this.courses$ = this.courses
    .valueChanges()

  }
  addCourse(course: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.courses.push([course.value]);
    course.value = '';
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/adding-an-object-to-firebase-rnjcpj?file=src/app/app.component.ts